# oneToMany/ManyToOne objects stale when updated outside the application

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, smartgwt, glassfish-4.1

This started recently, I can't track down what caused it or how to fix it.
I have 2 objects related to each other through a join

child entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "child", cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name="CHILD_ID", nullable=false)
private List<Parent> userCommunityOrganization = new ArrayList<Parent>();
```

parent entity:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID", referencedColumnName = "CHILD_ID")
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE },optional = false)
private Child child;
```

Querying the data in the app looks something like this:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT p.child FROM Parent p "
      + "WHERE p.community.communityId = :communityId ")
      .setParameter("communityId", communityId)
      .setHint(TopLinkQueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE);
```

Symptoms:

Update a parent field directly in the database (change status from active to inactive) - or any other relationship.

Access the child object in the application,
parent field in application is stale (ex status = active) and will remain so until server restart or app redeploy.

This does not affect child, updates to the db are reflected for child in the app when re-queried.

This is happening for all relationships in all entities.
I've tried changing caching:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

dropping back to javaEE 6 from javaEE 7 (that was the only system wide change since the problem started).

No joy.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE WITH FIX**

I replaced these lines:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

With:

```
<property name="toplink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Now all my relationships are in sync when updated in the database.  I'm using toplink and even though eclipselink is a subset of TL, I guess that doesn't extend to all the parameters.
eclipselink.query-results-cache doesn't do anything, at one point I was using a named query, but adding query hints during execution eliminates query caching for named queries.

But I'm still left with "why?".  What application wide change would cause this change in behavior?

environment:

- java 7
- glassfish 4.1
- jpa 1.0 (don't judge me)
- toplink/eclipselink
- gwt 2.3
- smartgwt
- MySql

Comment: What package is the TopLinkQueryHints from? if it is from TopLink essentials, it is based on TopLink, NOT based on EclipseLink and might explain why the EclipseLink query hints are ignored.  It does not explain why this ever worked - are you sure it was 'working' and not just that you didn't notice any issues due to timing?

Comment: It's from oracle.toplink.essentials.  It makes me feel better that this should never have worked, but I have confirmed that it does work in our production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on the Child with a refresh hint forcing only the child and its relations to be refreshed, not referenced entities.  If you want the referenced entities to also be refreshed, you must mark those relationships with the cascade refresh option.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, this worked until recently.  It's happening with all objects with relationships across the entire application, those query hints have remained unchanged.  I'll update the question with a solution, but I still don't know what caused the problem.

Comment: Refresh only works on the entity directly being queried.  You application might have been querying on the child and parent entities directly in other threads, which would have caused them to be independently refreshed and appear refreshed depending on the timing of the queries - but without the cascade setting, there is no way the referenced entity should get refreshed with the query you have shown.